# Texture comes out yellow, red, black and green on model

Tags: photogrammetry

I am having some issues with my Blender version 2.82.7 that I simply do not understand. I am working with my photogrammetry model which has a perfectly fine UV map and disfuse map, however when I import it into my own Blender project, and check the image texture in Shader Editor, it turns yellow, green, red and black (see reference picture). Has anyone experienced this problem before? I am running out of ideas as to how to fix this.

[image]

[image]

][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpy9l.jpg)

Comment: Please show the shader as  Blender screen capture.

Comment: Hi, I have added a screen capture in the description.

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi, does Blend-Exchange normally have difficulties with larger .blend files of 380MB? It seems as if it doesn't want to upload correctly.

Comment: I guess your machine can't handle that large texture. I'd suggest scale it down and try again.

Comment: The colors are a direct depiction XY plane  of a texture-space, without the lookup of the texture in the way..  As if, whatever material the object is using, the texture _coordinate_ is plugged straight into the output.

Comment: I suggest you upload more images in your question if you can't uploaf the file somewhere. Screenshots of: UV map, shader node tree, etc. As the material icon looks like it is on the model, there is something in the material or the image format. Can you indicate this format? Also where the image on the left comes from? Is left from another version of blender? Are you using an older version yourself (right part?) ? And this is a mesh with faces, not point cloud or other?